# Typo3 Fluid Image ViewHelper and uploads directory

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-flow, viewhelper

I am trying to use page content images in typo3 pages. I have uploaded 2 images and in DB only the filenames are stored.

OK - I found the images in uploads direcory!
But now how I have to display the image?!

I can hrdcode the upload dir url and add the filename from db, but It's realy ugly and not flexible.

I tryed to use `<f:image />` but no chance since it's expecting a resource path?!
OK - I found the resource dir but I can't upload images there from the standart typo3 page in cms.

The `<f:image />` is realy usefull for me because I need to display images in different sizes and crop them. This all is implemented in the ViewHelper, but I can not tell the ViewHelper to take my image in upload dir.

Please help me how to use the images on pages. The menu for uploading images on page contrent is realy usefull in backend, but I can not display the result in frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, the upload directory is set in the `TCA columns config (uploadfolder)`, you can write [your own viewHelper](http://www.t3node.com/blog/writing-a-basic-fluid-viewhelper-for-typo3/) and get the upload directory e.g.

```
/**
 * @param Tx_(extkey)_Domain_Model_(entity class) $entity 
 * @return string rendered image tags
 */
public function render($entity) {

    $html = '';

    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->includeTCA();
    $uploadfolder = $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_(extkey)_domain_model_(entity class)']['columns']['(column_name)']['config']['uploadfolder'];

    $images = explode(',', $entity->getImages());

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $html .= $this->getImageTag($uploadfolder, $image, $width);
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Have a look at the `Tx_Fluid_ViewHelpers_ImageViewHelper` class (especially the `render` method) for code to format your image tags.

Answer (score 1):

try using something like this: `<f:image src="uploads/tx_extensionname/{object.image}" alt="foo" title="bar" maxHeight="50" />`

[See the Fluid Wiki Page](http://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#f%3aimage)